# DESC on equal values suddenly changed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which fetches two rows -

```
SELECT tb.type,
                tb.value,
                tb.comp,
                tb.start_date,
                tb.end_date,
                tb.newdays,
                tb.modif_date
           FROM table_name tb
          WHERE tb.start_date <= sysdate
            AND tb.end_date >= sysdate
            AND tb.VALUE='ABC'
             ORDER BY tb.value, 
                tb.type DESC
```

Now this previously used to result in this form

```
+------+-------+------+------------+-----------+---------+------------------+
| TYPE | VALUE | COMP | START_DATE | END_DATE  | NEWDAYS |    MODIF_DATE    |
+------+-------+------+------------+-----------+---------+------------------+
| N    | ABC   | **   | 10-Mar-16  | 31-Dec-99 |       4 | 10/03/2016 10:05 |
| N    | ABC   | **   | 07-Mar-16  | 31-Dec-99 |       6 | 07/03/2016 23:23 |
+------+-------+------+------------+-----------+---------+------------------+
```

Recently I noticed the output now is like this (6 being above and 4 being below)

```
+------+-------+------+------------+-----------+---------+------------------+
| TYPE | VALUE | COMP | START_DATE | END_DATE  | NEWDAYS |    MODIF_DATE    |
+------+-------+------+------------+-----------+---------+------------------+
| N    | ABC   | **   | 07-Mar-16  | 31-Dec-99 |       6 | 07/03/2016 23:23 |
| N    | ABC   | **   | 10-Mar-16  | 31-Dec-99 |       4 | 10/03/2016 10:05 |
+------+-------+------+------------+-----------+---------+------------------+
```

If I remove the ORDER BY CLAUSE `tb.type`. The result is back to normal again (4 being at the top)

**Confusion** - 
1. Why/How did it suddenly changed ? 
2. Even though tb.type are equal i.e. `TYPE='N'`, why does the database orders/sorts it ? Since both values are equal, no ordering should happen, right?

***EDIT - If I remove tb.type, the sort is again back to normal. However when I put it back, the sort puts 6 at top. ***

> This means the sorting is not arbitrary.

**My Analysis** -
Usually the way it is stored in indexed structure is used when two values are equal. But the last DDL date(rebuild date) for index is in 2015. This means index is still the same.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Does the `last_analyzed` date in `user_tables` or `user_indexes` reflect the time the behaviour changed? I imagine Oracle did a parse that changed the execution plan (due to stats refresh). It might be worth looking at the execution plan for the query now with and without the `tb.type` order, and if you can get it the plan it used before the change for the real query. But ultimately you've been 'lucky' to get the result you expect so far; Gordon is right, the order the results are given is indeterminate then type and value are the same.

Comment: See also: [Order in the court!](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/order-in-court.html) for Tom Kyte's much-quoted treatise on the subject.

Comment: @AlexPoole The last_analyzed is yesterday's date. It analyses every 7 days, I guess.

Comment: As others have said: any ordering you see on identical values is pure coincidence. Unless you specify a unique order by combination there is no guarantee on the order of the rows. The "non-deterministic" ordering is influenced by a many things. DML on the table may change the physical location, concurrent read access to the table might change the order in which the rows are retrieved, a change in the execution plan might change the access methods and the order in which rows are retrieved. Not even an "index scan" _guarantees_ that rows are returned in the order they are stored in the index

Answer (score 3):

SQL in general -- and Oracle in particular -- do not implement stable sorts.  A stable sort is one that preserves the original ordering of the records.

SQL tables and results sets have no inherent ordering.  If you want stability, the keys in the `order by` need (in combination) to be unique, regardless of any indexing on the table.

Comment: It has been same for around 7 years. You mean to say that it was arbitrary ordering from last 7 years and now it changed suddenly because of unstable sort or oracle?

Comment: Until Oracle 10g, Oracle often used a query strategy that provided consistent sort results for columns not included in the `order by` clause.  But the documentation has always been correct.

Comment: @PirateX - the result set order has been indeterminate for the last seven years, yes; the 'sudden change' could be down to the optimiser doing something differently on the most recent hard parse, due to data or stats; or just the order data blocks are retrieved for these particular rows.

Comment: @PirateX - YES! For seven years you took advantage of an "accident of implementation" that worked in your favor, with no specific promise from Oracle that you should EXPECT that result. "Use at your own peril" is what I always say when I see this kind of code. If you want guarantees (or almost guarantees), write code based on documented behavior of the software. For example, 7 years ago you could have had the order by clause written as `order by tb.value, tb.type desc, newdays, start_date`(or any other sort order you need).

Comment: @gordon -  I tried removing tb.type. It sorts the way I want (4 at top). But if I put it back, the sort makes 6 at top. Hence it's not arbitrary!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation clearly states that 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm

> **order_by_clause**
>
> Use the ORDER BY clause to order rows returned by the statement.
>   **Without an order_by_clause, no guarantee exists that the same query
>   executed more than once will retrieve rows in the same order.**

---

> 1. Why/How did it suddenly changed ?

Because the database choosed alternative access path than previous one, most likely due to a table growth, a statistics refresh or because some index was created or dropped.

Please take a look at the following simple example:

```
create table tetest1 as
select t.*, sysdate - dbms_random.value * 10000 as myDate
from all_objects t;
;
select object_id, object_type 
from tetest1
where mydate > sysdate - 2
and object_id between 21000 and 50000
order by object_type;

 OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE           
---------- -----------------------
     47034 JAVA CLASS              
     31660 JAVA CLASS              
     47427 SYNONYM                 
     46113 SYNONYM                 
     26042 SYNONYM                 
     21259 SYNONYM                 
     33351 SYNONYM
```

And now the same data, but an index is created:

```
create index my_idx1 on tetest1( mydate );
select object_id, object_type 
from tetest1
where mydate > sysdate - 2
and object_id between 21000 and 50000
order by object_type;

index MY_IDX1 created.
 OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE           
---------- -----------------------
     31660 JAVA CLASS              
     47034 JAVA CLASS              
     26042 SYNONYM                 
     33351 SYNONYM                 
     21259 SYNONYM                 
     47427 SYNONYM                 
     46113 SYNONYM
```

In the first case the database uses a full table scan.
In the second case the database uses an index (different access path), and rows order is different - but in both cases it meets a requirement stated in the query `order by object_type`

---

If you want data to be  sorted also by NEWDAYS columns, use just:

```
ORDER BY tb.value, 
         tb.type DESC,
         tb.NEWDAYS
```